# What is a word for when you don't want to do something, but enjoy it when you do it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find a word to describe a situation where you don't want to do something, but enjoy it when you do it. For example, going to the gym, travelling a long distance to see a friend.

I have tried searching but no luck so far.

Comment: Describe it in what way? Do you want a noun for an activity like that, or an adjective to describe something like that, or something else? An example sentence showing how you would like to use the word would help people give more useful suggestions.

Comment: Not a single word: "reluctantly but without regret".

Comment: Not one word (unless you hyphenate it), but what you describe sounds like the opposite of “grinning and bearing it,” so maybe you could call it a “**bear-and-grin[-it]**” experience.

Comment: The phrase *pleasantly surprised* is often used for an event that you expect to be a burden but is enjoyable. However it is usually used for one-off situations rather than a routine, such as the gym

Comment: Please see: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: As Fifth Harmony song goes, because those things are **worth it** https://g.co/kgs/3KqfQ

Comment: It's a "Green-eggs-and-ham moment": *Say!
I like green eggs and ham!
I do! I like them, Sam-I-am!*

Answer (score 2):

If you are reluctant to do something but you force yourself to anyway, you might be doing it **begrudgingly**.

Answer (score -2):

Obligation would fit.  It describes something that we are obliged to do, with the connotation that we don't necessarily enjoy the activity.

> How do you like sweeping the floor?
>
> It's an obligation.

Comment: I don't think it would fit, because the question asks for a word with the connotation that we do enjoy an activity, we just don't want to do it.

Comment: to further the point @sumelic is making, the OP specifically states that the enjoyment comes *after* being "forced" into doing the activity. But *obligation* has no positive connotation to it at all.

Comment: Yup, somehow the "enjoyment" aspect didn't quite sink in.  I think badministrator's answer hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score -2):

"Obligatory" would fit.It's the correct Adverb.